# Inserting a Python List in SQL Table

Tags: python, mysql

I have a python list like `L = [1,5,4,2,5,6,...around 100 elements]` and an SQL table with 100 columns. I want to insert each element of `L` in the corresponding column in SQL Table. For an example, 1 gets inserted in column 1 and 5 gets inserted in column 2 (in the same row). The SQL query will be like `INSERT into table (0,1,2,3,4 ... 100 column names) values (%s, %s, %s, %s .... 100 times)`
Can there be a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Don't you already have 0 as Index on your SQL?

Comment: @Rizzit Sorry I didn't understand

Comment: `INSERT into table (0,`

Comment: @Rizzit He wants to add values in all the 100 entries. Not only 0 and 5.

Comment: @DazzleR He wants to add all 100 values in 100 columns, therefor I need to know if I have to equate for the primary key in his SQL using `enumerate` in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your question is only about syntax, you can use a list containing field names and question marks for the values.

Something like this (not tested):

```
field_names = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3') # and so on
insert_data = ('value1', 'value2', 'value3') # and so on

db_connection.execute('INSERT INTO table (' + ','.join(field_names) + ') VALUES (' + ','.join('?' * len(insert_data)) + ')' , insert_data)
```

If your data count is the same as your table field's count, you can omit the field names (i.e. if you have 100 fields, 100 values and the values are already sorted in the same way that the fields were declared when creating the table).

Answer (score 1):

In this example:

```
lst = ['2', '5', '0', '1', '9']
for i in enumerate(lst):
    print i
```

we get this results as a tuple:

```
(0, '2')
(1, '5')
(2, '0')
(3, '1')
(4, '9')
```

i[0] represents the 0'th element in your list and the 0'th column in your SQL. so we save the 0'th value (which is 2) into the 0'ths column, and so on.

so we write a function for this:

```
def inserting():
    cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO table(i[0]) \
    VALUES (%s) """, (i[1])
    cursor.close()
```

and then:

```
for i in enumerate(L):
    inserting()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas library as follows:

First, convert your list into a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

df = pd.DataFrame([L])
```

The output will be a dataframe with one row and generic columns and index:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6 
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

And then just use the `to_sql` command to insert the row into your table. The doc of the method is in http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html. So, it will look similar to:

```
df.to_sql(table_name, connection, ...) # Look at the rest of the parameters if necessary.
```

The connection parameter refers to the connection with the database and must be established before this line of code.

Answer (score 0):

q: the first part of query,
v: second part, for `%s`s

```
q = "insert into table ("
for i in range(100):
    q += str(i) + ", "
q += "100)"
v = "values ("
for i in range(100):
    v += "%s, "
v += "%s)"

insert_query = q+v
conn.execute(insert_query, data_list)
```